# Centering a flot chart relative to the chart plotted instead of the canvas size.

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, flot

Hey I'm working on application that uses Flot charts fairly extensively. My manager tasked me with "centering" the charts as he does not like the way they look right now.

By default they generate with a canvas size that leaves room on the y-axis for data, and this leads to an offset where the canvas is centered leaving the chart slight offset to the right.

I know this is a nitpicky issue but I'm wondering if there's an easily implementable way to make the chart center relative to the chart itself, possibly by extending the right-side canvas to equal the left, or by making the y-axis generate in a text form leaving only the chart as a canvas.

I've tried to read through the flot API for a solution but nothing obviously jumps out at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are looking for the grid's margin [property](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid).

```
grid:{
    margin:{
       right: 17,
       top: 17
    }
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvm8z/1/).

**FOR COMMENT**

To set the right margin equal to the left margin dynamically, I would let flot draw the plot once, set the right margin equal to the yaxis's width and then redraw the plot:

```
p = $.plot( ...
p.getOptions().grid.margin.right = p.getYAxes()[0].box.width;   
p.setupGrid();
p.draw();
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvm8z/2/).  Run it multple times to see how it works dynamically.

Comment: I could manually solve my issue that way by offsetting the right, I would like a way to make it scalable for graphs of any size.

Comment: In the chart I'm using the y and x-axis appear to be generated within the canvas. That isn't the case in your example, can't say I'm 100% sure why though.

Comment: @Illustrated, see above edit for my attempt at automating setting the margin property.